# Memory used by JVM for each process

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I have a web application . so , I want to test that how much memory is getting used by JVM for each process . Like , I have a login page , so for that how much memory it takes. Same , I have a Uploading a document for that also i want to check the memory used by JVM. So, How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that precisely, because a lot of objects are shared in typical java web application.

You could try with [Yourkit](http://yourkit.com/), it has a section for webapps that you can look at after you connect to the running application.